# Are there infinite solutions $(a\in\mathbb{Z},b\in\mathbb{N},p,q)$ that satisfy $p=qb^4-a^2$, where $p<q$ are odd primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

I have the equation $p=qb^4-a^2$, where $p<q$ are odd primes and $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in\mathbb{N}$.

Is it either provable or is there a conjecture for the existence of infinite many solutions $(a,b,p,q)$?

*What I know so far:*

I found in Bordellès Book "Arithmetic Tales. Advanced Edition" (page 295) that according to Polignac's conjecture (which isn't proved), there are infinitely many examples per any even difference of both primes for the slightly different case: $q=pb^4+a^2$.

I would already be very happy to know if there is any theorem or conjecture that says there are infinitely many solutions for my current case $p=qb^4-a^2$.

Comment: Putting $b=1$ and $a=2$ then the problem turns into the [Polignac's conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture)

Comment: Putting $p=2$ and $b=1$ the problem turns in the following: are there infinite many prime numbers $q=a^2+2$. I believe this fact is much easier to prove.

Comment: @lonestudent: Thank you for this special case. It would be interesting to know if other solutions can be parametrized explicitely.

Comment: Ivan's suggestion can be extended. If for any prime $p$ , $a^2+p$ produces infinite many primes, we would be done. Unfortunately, this is open as well, but we can safely assume it since the case $p=2$ is almost surely already sufficient. What has been proven is that $a^2+b^4$ produces infinite many primes , but I do not think that this can be used here.

Comment: lone students approach works if any even square difference occurs infinite many often as a prime gap, this is also unknown , but again can safely be assumed since already the case $a=2$ should be sufficient. In total, the conjecture seems to be inevitably true, but I think we won't nevertheless be able to prove it.

Comment: @Asher2211, Yes, I forgot it.

Comment: @Asher2211 This can easily be repaired , see my comment.

Comment: I believe, there are infinite many primes $a^2+3$, but if the question is still open, maybe it is not so easy to prove. But it is definitely easier than common case.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu It is at least as easy to prove the conjecture as to prove this particular case , because a proof of this case would proof the conjecture. In fact, the conjecture is much "easier" to prove than this particular case, but I see no possibility to actually do it.

Comment: @Peter To answer the question conclusively, I think knowing where the problem is coming from would be a good option.

Comment: I just noticed that we even only need that infinite many prime pairs $(p,q)$ have ANY square difference. Although this is surely open as well, it makes the conjecture even more likely to be true. We would only need ONE pair for each of the even squares $4,16,36,64,100,\cdots $

Comment: Let me give the background of this problem: I am studying elliptic curves of the form $y^2=x^3-pqx$ and found out that the solution of the given equation ensures rational points on this curve.

Comment: @EldarSultanow Does that mean that $p,q$ are given and that we want to decide whether infinite many $a,b$ do the job ? This would be something completely different.

Comment: @Peter: We are searching for quadruples $(a,b,p,q)$. Hence our search space is "big enough". Both odd primes $2<p<q$ must not be given (they are flexible parameters).